# Can't populate test postgres db on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec

I've switched form SQLite to PostgreSQL for rspec testing by setting my database.yml file:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testdb
  hostname: localhost
  pool: 10
  username: USERNAME
  password: PASSWORD
```

I've ran a `rake db:migrate` and have verified that the tables/columns are generated as a result by using the psql console.

I've attempted to run my rspec controller tests but I get a bunch of errors saying that it could find a model with id=whatever

Next, I go into my rails console via `rails console test` and create a model with `model.create!(valid attributes here)` I end up getting the commit message indicating that it was successful, however, running a `Model.find(1)` yields an ActiveRecord error saying that there's nothing there...

Another experiment I have tried is to point my 'test' at my development database (also running psql), and the tests pass successfully as they should, so there's definitely something up with my test PostgreSQL database.

If there's any special files or permissions that I might need to take a look at then any help would be highly appreciated!

Update: Attempted a `rake db:test:prepare` and checked the test db with both the psql console and rails console... no data has been copied from my development database to the test database O.O

Comment: try 'rake db:test:prepare' to clone the database ove

Answer (score 0):

run `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset`